# Get array of unique elements from Mysql

Tags: java, mysql, database

I have such query:

```
SELECT id, forum_theme, owner, enter_time, main_topic 
FROM forum_message 
WHERE main_topic IN (1,2,3)
ORDER BY enter_time DESC
LIMIT 3
```

Array is changing, and I'm adding it in java, so LIMIT equals size of array. 
Problem is - I need every record unique by main_topic, so each element of array must have only one record, but instead I'm having 1, 2, 2 topic records, etc.

*How can I change my query to maki it possible?*

Comment: DISTINCT from SQL side, Set from Java side ?

Comment: Which one do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT id, forum_theme, owner, enter_time, main_topic 
FROM forum_message 
WHERE main_topic IN (1,2,3)
GROUP BY main_topic
ORDER BY enter_time DESC
LIMIT 3
```

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Use distinct keyword to select main_topcs as follows:

```
SELECT id, forum_theme, owner, enter_time, main_topic 
FROM forum_message 
WHERE main_topic IN ( select distinct (main_topic) from forum_message)
ORDER BY enter_time DESC
```

Note: Remember if you put id or others columns they you will get more than one main_topcs

Comment: If I did **SELECT distinct(main_topic), id, enter_time FROM forum_message WHERE main_topic IN (1,2,3,4) ORDER BY enter_time DESC LIMIT 4** I will recieve unique records, but not unique main_topic in each record - they mustn't be repeated, but if **distinct(main_topic)** without other fileds - it works well, I need more information in records.

Comment: See, what I need is main_topic 1 - one record, 2 - other, 3 - other, only main_topic must be unique and therefore only one record for ech topic would be. So how to do it right?